# Having trouble printing out my 'receipt' on my C++ invoice program: Function for some reason not working

Tags: c++, function, invoice

Trying to wrap up my invoice program. I'm trying to get my customerInvoice function to properly display. However whenever I try to use it, I get an error. For some reason this function is having a difficult time displaying, and I'm not sure what the complication is. I can enter my values in just fine, none of the other variables are having a hang-up, I'm just getting a bit stalled on this part as its not properly displaying the message inside the customerInvoice function.

I also want my invoice to recognize the senior discount: if the customers age is over 60, then they get the 0.05 multiplier discount on their purchase.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


const float flatTaxRate = 0.08;
const float seniorDiscountRate = 0.05;

int getIntValue (string toInput){
    cout << "Please enter " << toInput <<": ";
    int value;
    cin >> value;
    return value;
}

string choiceOfItem(int choice) {
    return choice == 1 ? "Bread" :
           choice == 2 ? "Milk" :
           choice == 3 ? "Soap" :
           choice == 4 ? "Eggs" :
           choice == 5 ? "Deodorant" :
           choice == 6 ? "Juice" :
           choice == 7 ? "Chips" :
           choice == 8 ? "Forks" :
           choice == 9 ? "Spoons" :
           choice == 10 ? "Cups" :
    "Invalid Item: Select Again";
}

int getIntInputValues (string toInput){
    cout << "Please enter " << toInput <<": ";
    int value;
    cin >> value;
    return value;
}

double getDoubleInputValues (string toInput){
    cout << "Please enter " << toInput <<": ";
    double value;
    cin >> value;
    return value;
}

bool customerAge(int age){
    const int seniorCustomer = 60;
    return age >= seniorCustomer;
}

void customerInvoice(int choice, double price, int age)
{
    cout << "-----------------------------------\n";
    cout << "\n" << "Invoice" << "\n";
    //can use \n as a tab
    
    if(seniorCustomer(age))
    {
        price -= price * seniorDiscountRate;
    }
     
    cout << choiceOfItem(choice) <<":" << "\n" <<"$"<< price << endl;
    cout << "Tax:" << "\n" <<"$"<< price * flatTaxRate << endl;
    cout << "Discount:" << "\n" <<"$"<< "-" << price * seniorDiscountRate << endl;
    cout << "Total:" << "\n"<< "$" << price + (price * flatTaxRate) << endl;
    cout << "-----------------------------------\n";
}
 



int main()
{
    const int MIN_VALID = 1;
    const int MAX_VALID = 10;

    cout << "What would you like to buy?" << endl;
    
    for (int choice = MIN_VALID; choice <=MAX_VALID; ++choice)
    {
        cout << choice << ". " << choiceOfItem(choice)<< endl;
    }
    cout << endl;    

    int choice = getIntValue("your choice");

   
    while (choice < MIN_VALID || choice > MAX_VALID)
    {
        cout << "Sorry, " << choice << " wasn't a valid choice" << endl;
        cout << "Please try again:" << endl;
        choice = getIntValue("your choice");
    }
    
    double price = getDoubleInputValues("price");

    
    int age = getIntInputValues("age");

       
    bool seniorCustomer;
       
    cout << " " << endl;
        
    customerInvoice;
    
    cout << choiceOfItem(choice) << endl;
    cout << price << endl;
    cout << age << endl;
    cout << seniorCustomer;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `main()`, replace this `customerInvoice` with `customerInvoice(choice, price, age);` i.e. pass the arguments to `customerInvoice()` function.

Comment: *For some reason this function is having a difficult time displaying* -- You need to tell us exactly what "a difficult time displaying" means.  The program is doing exactly as you wrote it.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "However whenever I try to use it, I get an error." **What error**? **What do you mean by** "try to use it"? Is it when you are **compiling** the program, or **running** it? "For some reason this function is having a difficult time displaying, and I'm not sure what the complication is." **What does that mean**? **What happens** when you "try to use it" (as you say), and **how is that different** from what you expect to happen?

Comment: Also, please try to think clearly about the problem, and then describe clearly. For example, you aren't trying to "display the function"; rather, the *code in the function* is written to display *some information*. Right? So. **Does the function get called**? (Do you know how to check?) If it gets called, **what happens when it is called**? Is **anything** displayed? Is it the wrong thing? Just what?

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `customerInvoice;`, exactly what do you think this should mean? Why should it mean that? For example, do you think this should cause the function to run? Why? (Hint: elsewhere in the code, where you write `getIntValue("your choice");`, **why did you (correctly) not** just write `getIntValue`?)

Comment: As on [a question you deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75845432/), the code in this question fails to be a [mre]. Your code attempts to show printing invoices instead of of focusing on demonstrating the error. Please focus your code so that there is a chance of it helping someone else in the future (and to make it easier on the people **volunteering** to help you).

Answer (score 2):

As noted in comments, the following in `main` does not equate to calling a function:

> ```
> customerInvoice;
> ```

Rather you want:

```
customerInvoice(choice, price, age);
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `main()` function, you have this statement:

```
customerInvoice;
```

`customerInvoice` is name of function and a function name is an expression, here it's result is unused. When compiling your program, compiler is giving this warning:

```
warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
customerInvoice;
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Instead, call `customerInvoice()` function and pass the appropriate arguments to it:

```
customerInvoice(choice, price, age);
```

*> I also want my invoice to recognize the senior discount: if the customers age is over 60, then they get the 0.05 multiplier discount on their purchase.*

Looks like you need to call `customerAge()` instead of `seniorCustomer()` function in `customerInvoice()` function. Moreover, there is no `seniorCustomer()` function in your program.
It would be much better if you rename your `customerAge()` function to `seniorCustomer()` as it is returning whether customer is a senior customer or not.